# Reading xml elements

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read an xml file structured as below

```
<dictionary>
<head>

<DNUM />
<DEF value="definition1" />
<EXAMPLE value="example of 1" />
<EXAMPLE value="example of 1" />

<DNUM />
<DEF value="definition2" />
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2" />
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2" />
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2" />
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2" />

<DNUM />
<DEF value="definition3" />
<EXAMPLE value="example of 3" />


</head>
</ dictionary>
```

With a code somehing like below I could read all definitions or examples inside "head" tag

```
 $result = $xml->xpath('//dictionary/head');
 while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
   foreach($node->DEF as $def){
        echo  $def["value"]."<br>\n";
   }
 }
```

But I want to get each definition and examples of that definition.  I think DNUM tag could be used for this but since it has no opening and closing seperatly I could not find out how I can get the result I want.

Comment: are you sure the xml is error free?

Comment: @ajreal: This is the structure used by a windows dictionary application. And it seems functioning right.

Comment: the xml is not valid .It should be </head> not <head> for the closing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question but if you need to find DEFs and examples of that DEF it can be like

```
    $result = $xml->xpath('//dictionary/head/DEF');
 while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
   foreach($node->EXAMPLE as $example){
        echo  $example["value"]."<br>\n";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SimpleXMLElement?

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$def = $sxe->head->dictionary->DEF->attributes(); //you can foreach this
//or
$def = $sxe['head']['dictionary']['DEF']->attributes(); //you can foreach this
```

You could get the examples in a similar fashion. SXEs can be used like objects or arrays and are iterative via foreach.

Personally I think SimpleXMLElement is the easiest way to work with XML and PHP.

Further Reading:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem in this way.

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//dictionary/headword/*[name()="DEF" or name()="EXAMPLE"]');
 foreach($result  as $res){
     echo $res["value"]."<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As your XML structure is not hierarchical, you can only count. For example the number of the following `DNUM` elements:

```
$name     = 'DNUM';
$elements = $xml->xpath("//$name");
$count    = count($elements);
foreach ($elements as $index => $element) {
    $count--;
    echo "Iteration $index\n";
    foreach ($element->xpath("following-sibling::*[count(./following-sibling::$name) = $count]") as $following) {
        echo $following->asXML(), "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

exemplary output:

```
Iteration 0
<DEF value="definition1"/>
<EXAMPLE value="example of 1"/>
<EXAMPLE value="example of 1"/>

Iteration 1
<DEF value="definition2"/>
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2"/>
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2"/>
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2"/>
<EXAMPLE value="example of 2"/>

Iteration 2
<DEF value="definition3"/>
<EXAMPLE value="example of 3"/>
```

Comment: I do not know much about usage of following-sibling.  I have just started reading about it. Anyway   the code only outputs "Iteration 0 / 1 / 2".

Comment: @mustafa: The output is as given in the anser. if you only see what you write you see you need to view the source in your browser, using the browser-window naturally won't display you XML.